# Complex Type requires primary key

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, primary-key

I have an object that contains an attribute with the type of another object, which I want to treat as Complex Type.

```
public class Location : IModule
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public Coordinate Coordinate { get; set; }
}

[ComplexType]
public class Coordinate
{
    public string Latitude { get; set; }
    public string Longitude { get; set; }
}
```

While adding a migration, I ran into the problem that a primary key is required (exactly what I want to prevent).

The entity type `Coordinate` requires a primary key to be defined.

**EDIT**

For performance reasons I want the properties being stored as `Coordinate_Latitude` and `Coordinate_Longitute` instead of having a reference to another table.

Comment: *exactly what I want to prevent*, **Why**?

Comment: see edit - for performance reasons

Comment: adding a primary (clustered) key will actually improve performance significantly

Comment: I do have a primary key on Location, I want to store the attributes of Coordinate within the same table as Location. So I disagree, saving these attributes in the same table will be more efficient than storing them in a different table referencing them. Adding a key to Coordinate would create another table which would lead to more IOs for every single query.

Comment: I'm asking about the Annotation ComplexType, which promises to store attributes in the same table.

Comment: @David Check my updated answer out. I have proposed another solution.

Comment: Does the DB you're working with not have a suitable `geography` data type? For instance, SQL Server does and there are .NET types that support this too.

Answer (score 7):

Based on this question ([How do I implement a simple "complex type" in Entity Framework Core 2/C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50572158/how-do-i-implement-a-simple-complex-type-in-entity-framework-core-2-c)), I found the answer: Owned entity types do the trick.

```
public class Location : IModule
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public Coordinate Coordinate { get; set; }
}

[Owned]
public class Coordinate
{
    public string Latitude { get; set; }
    public string Longitude { get; set; }
}
```

This creates a table containt the attributes `Id`, `Coordinate_Latitued`, `Coordinate_Longitude`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a key, to make it works. This is how the Entity Framework works, [Entity Framework needs to know the key to keep track on the object when you make an update or delete operation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15381324/2946329). Just if you don't want to manually insert it, you can declare it as an identity column to auto increment it. Something like this:

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int CoordinateKey { get; set; }
```

Or with Fluent-API:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Coordinate>().HasKey(u => u.CoordinateKey);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Coordinate>().Property(c => c.CoordinateKey)
                .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
}
```

**Edit**: It seems you want to treat the `Coordinate` class as a not mapped class. You can use `NotMapped` attribute. Have a look at the following question to know how:

[Entity Framework code first: How to ignore classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30643553/entity-framework-code-first-how-to-ignore-classes)

Comment: He clearly says he wants `Coordinate` to be a complex-type (which always has no key).