# Entityframework core code first migration of Complex type

Tags: entity-framework-core-2.1, entity-framework-core-2.2

I am creating a basic application using ef core. In it I have a Person and Address class. Address is a complex type. When I try to run migration command (add-migration initialmigration) by using Package Manager concole. It throws an exception. It says that I must define Id for this complex type. Below is the following code.

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}

public class Address 
{
    public String Street { get; private set; }
   

    private Address()
    {
    }

    public Address(string street)
    {
        Street = street;
      
    }       
}

public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext() { 
       
       
    }

    DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=.;Database=MyTest;Trusted_Connection=True;");
        }
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().Property(k => k.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Person>(entity => entity.OwnsMany(m => m.Addresses, address => 
            
            address.Property(x => x.Street).HasColumnName("Street")
            
            ));
    }
}
```

How could I solve this issues, so that I could migrate my complex type?

Comment: This thread about complex types requiring primary keys might help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53416869/7380348

Comment: I tried those solutions. It didn't help